# Position in item click listener does not refresh upon filtering

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a listview in android that is filterable by a searchview in the action bar.

Each item in the list is clickable, and takes you to a different photo. What I did for this was:

```
//inside  setOnItemClickListener...

                                String itemPosition = item.get(position).getItemURL();

                                Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("key", itemPosition.toString());

                                startActivity(i);
```

It works great if I don't use the search function.. But once you try filtering the list, it loads the photo of the item that used to be in the same position.

My question/s: is there a way to tell android to refresh the positions upon filtering? I figured that if the positions refreshed along with the list, it would work okay.

Also, is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Full code: ad is a custom baseadapter that takes in context, list, implements Filterable

```
                        ad = new GridViewAdapter(this, item);

                        SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(ad);
                        swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(activity_gridview_gv);

                        assert swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getViewAnimator() != null;
                        swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getViewAnimator().setInitialDelayMillis(DELAY);

                        activity_gridview_gv.setAdapter(swingBottomInAnimationAdapter);
                        activity_gridview_gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String itemPosition = item.get(position).getItemURL();

                                Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("key", itemPosition.toString());

                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: add this when you filter list,  notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I tried both your suggestions, doesn't work..

Comment: Please share code you are trying.

Comment: show your code for filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While everyone's answer is correct to some degree, it seems that I had a different issue at hand. The question is still valid and I will post my solution.

My problem wasn't with the adapter not being refreshed.

It was with the List "item" not being updated once the adapter is notified of the changes. See:

```
String itemPosition = item.get(position).getItemURL();
```

I never really updated "item". In fact, I was calling the old, unfiltered list! What happens next is the filter does work and update the list, but I end up using the old list "item". Therefore linking me to the former object in the same position.

The solution: Get the item's position on click.

Inside onItemClick:

```
MainGridItem filteredItem = (MainGridItem) ad.getItem(position);
String itemPosition = filteredItem.get(position).getItemURL();
```

What this does is get the position of the clicked item. Now, you end up with the correct position upon clicking.

Also, please let me know if there is a better way of doing what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Write list getter and setter in your adapter.
Set new filtered list to adapter and perform

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I have the exact same thing in my code already. It works in filtering the list and showing the correct items, but it doesn't refresh the position in the list.

Comment: Have you checked you are getting position from same list that is updated. Or it may be older list.